# Unity won't export iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, export

i am trying to export my Unity Project to iOS (which has worked before), but then I downgraded from the newest Unity (5. something) to 4.6.7f, and now Unity won't even start exporting the project. It gives no errors, nothing. I also downgraded from XCode 7 to 6.4

As always, I set the player settings for iOS, click Build & Run, tell the program the location, hit save... nothing happens. The window "Build settings" keeps opened and I can just try over and over.

I tried a clean reinstall of XCode and Unity too, but to no avail. Does anyone have experienced this issue before?

Kind regards
Sebastian

Comment: Are you using El Capitan by any chance?

Comment: Yes, do you think it was something to do with the writing priviliges to /usr/bin? That would be weird, because it used to work on El Capitan as well

Comment: I'm not sure, but it wouldn't work for me either. I disabled SIP by rebooting to the recovery partition and running csrutil disable in the terminal. Then I installed the latest patch from [this page](http://unity3d.com/unity/qa/patch-releases) which fixed the issue.

Comment: Care to explain what exactly those are? I have never before heard of them :) Thanks in advance

Comment: SIP (System Integrity Protection) basically removes full access privileges to a number of system files and folders more detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection), it was introduced in El Capitan. "csrutil disable" basically turns it off. If I were you I would try installing the latest patch first, SIP may or may not be related.

Comment: Cheers, downloading patches now :) I'll let you know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94196/discussion-between-coernel-and-ben-kelly).